# Xcode 5.0.2 crashes on start-up (OSAKit plugin - code signature invalid)

Tags: ios, xcode

Today Xcode is crashing for me every time I start it up.  When I last used it last week it was working fine and I haven't changed anything.

I've tried reinstalling Xcode but it has made no difference.  Does anybody have any ideas how I can get it working again?

```
Process:         Xcode [1062]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.2 (3335.32)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335032000000000~4
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 106632651
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [260]
Responsible:     Xcode [1062]
User ID:         501

PlugIn Path:       /System/Library/Frameworks/OSAKit.framework/Versions/A/OSAKit
PlugIn Identifier: com.apple.OSAKit
PlugIn Version:    1.4 (89)

Date/Time:       2014-01-14 14:09:05.686 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  B2D995CA-38C1-0B1C-DA4E-8DD870BE2A37


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: DVTPlugInExtensionFaultingLock

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0x7fff7692ee40 (cr2):
    __DATA                 00007fff7691b000-00007fff76920000 [   20K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/Versions/A/CoreServicesInternal
--> __DATA                 00007fff76920000-00007fff76936000 [   88K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/OSAKit.framework/Versions/A/OSAKit
    __DATA                 00007fff76936000-00007fff76937000 [    4K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A3005
```

Comment: Looks like corruption of a system framework.  Not sure how to fix it though - might even need to re-install OSX.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks. Your comment prompted me to try copying the OSAKit.framework files from another Mac and that seems to have solved the problem. That said, the only other Mac I have access to right now is running Snow Leopard so these files may well be out-of-date and cause problems later on but at least I don't have to reinstall OS X right now.  I'll see if I can get somebody to provide me with the Mavericks versions.

Comment: Yikes! :)  Yeah get one from someone with 10.9.{0,1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by trojanfoe in the comment above, the OSAKit framework had become corrupted somehow.  Copying an uncorrupted version of the files from another machine fixed the problem.